# Sending data with email

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a google-app-maker, and it show some row data table. Every time it's row clicked, it will go to a page. And on that page there is button for sending invoice information. So recipient is static.

Client Name : Name_of_Client

But I can not grab field Name_of_Client into Msg

OnClick Script :

```
/* var widgets = widget.parent.descendants; */
var to = "webmaster@domain.com";
var subject = "Invoice Report";
var msg = "Client Name widget.datasource.item.Client_Name";
/* widgets.EmailStatus.text = 'Sending email...'; */

SendEmail(to, subject, msg);
```

Client Script :

```
function  clearEmailForm(){
}

function SendEmail(To, Subject, Msg){
var status = "sending";
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
status.text = 'Email sent...';
clearEmailForm();
 })
 .SendEmail(To, Subject, Msg);  
}
```

Server Script :

```
function SendEmail(to, subject, msg){
MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject , msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The widget reference should be outside the string:

```
var msg = "Client Name " + widget.datasource.item.Client_Name;
```

Sometimes widgets don't inherit the datasource as expected, so you may need to reference the page or page fragment by using `parent` or `root`.

```
var msg = "Client Name " + widget.root.datasource.item.Client_Name;
```